# Link to the Model element from search results (Chewy, Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, elasticsearch, view, chewy-gem

I have implemented a search for User model (Elasticsearch using Chewy gem).

views/search/search.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: "get" do %>
    <%= label_tag(:q, "Search by name/ surname/ email:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>

<% @results.each do |r| %>
   <%= r.name %> 
   <%= r.surname %>,
   <%= r.email %>, 
<% end %>
```

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users
resources :users, only: [:show], controller: :profiles
```

What I need is to add a link to a user for each search result line. (How to connect Chewy users indexes with user pages)

update:

I changed the last paragraph in search.html.erb to:

```
<% @results.each do |r| %>
<%= link_to r.name, user_path(r) %> 
<%= r.surname %>,
<%= r.email %>, 
<% end %>
```

The search results are clickable now but I get the following error:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProfilesController#show
Couldn't find User with 'id'=#UsersIndex::User:0x007fa1050ebed0>

my profiles_controller.rb:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])   //this line gets an error
end
end
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Does this have anything to do with chewy, or with elastic search?  Do you just need to know how to create a link in a view?

Comment: na id does not. its just a standard rails question, imo

Comment: Standard rails question, right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look to `rake routes` which is listing all routes and their names

resources :name is generating all the default routes (where you just 
specified to make the show_route)

```
<% @results.each do |r| %>
   <%= link_to r.name, user_path(r.id) %> 
   <%= r.surname %>,
   <%= r.email %>, 
<% end %>
```

or, maybe more advanced

```
<% @results.each do |r| %>
   <%= link_to user_path(r.id) do %> 
     <%= r.name %>,
     <%= r.surname %>,
     <%= r.email %>
   <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

you are throwing the id of the result into the user_path() helper, which will genreate /user/12

Comment: it works but after click on the link I get an error - it looks like I need to add some details to my question

Comment: if u click on the liink the url is /user/1337 - so thats going into profiles_controller and the action is "def show".

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProfilesController#show
Couldn't find User with 'id'=#<UsersIndex::User:0x007fa1050ebed0>

profiles_controller:     def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end

Comment: so lets face it. you asked for the link to model and we answered. obviously you need to change to user_path(r.id) or in your model override def to_params